# Accessing UI thread in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.android

My application sends and receives TCP strings. One of those strings is to make an object visible depending on the string. My current code gives `System.NullReferenceException has been thrown Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

I can't find the right method to access, I guess as RunOnUI doesn't seem to access this right.

My current code:

Listener class: (Snippet of the full class, I can post more if needed).

```cs
public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
    String content = string.Empty;

    StateObject so = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handle = so.workSocket;

    int bytesRead = handle.EndReceive(ar);

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        so.sb.Append(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(so.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
        content = so.sb.ToString();
    }
    if (content.IndexOf("0") > -1)
    {
        ma.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            //This is where the received data is passed
            ma.SortData(content);
        });
        Send(handle, content);
    }
    else
    {
        handle.BeginReceive(so.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), so);
    }
}
```

And the code for SortData:

```cs
public void SortData(string data)
{
    if(data == "0")
    {
        txtmsg.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;        
    }
} //This is the only code that's called, the txtmsg.Visibility part is the error producer once called.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the Context to your class in a constructor

so you would add a constructor to your class like :

```
MainActivity mContext;

public YourClass(MainActivity context) {
       this.mContext = context;
}
```

and then call the method from your class like :

```
mContext.RunOnUiThread(() =>
     {
       //This is where the received data is passed
       mContext.SortData(content);
     });
```